# Xampp - Can see files through network but php, css, etc not working

Tags: php, css, apache, xampp

I searched but couldn't find the answer to this specific question.

I'm running XAMPP for windows and it's working fine on my local machine but when I try to access Wordpress through the network all I get is the index page. The pages aren't formatted properly and the links don't work. PHP isn't working through the network.

This works on my local machine: "http://192.168.x.xxx/mysite/wordpress/" but when accessing it through the network, I get the problem above.

How can I get this to work so that someone in the next office can view the sites properly too?

Comment: Can't put my finger on it exactly (otherwise this would be an answer and not a comment), but I'm thinking it's a File Sharing & Security issue.

Comment: What do you mean, "through the network"? You're loading the files directly over a Windows share?

Comment: Yes. Through a Windows share. Can see files but services not working. It's weird.

Comment: @MarcB My guess is OP means over the LAN, but it's not totally clear.

Comment: Okay. I can't believe I wasted your time on this but I think it's working and the problem is that the links to the links and CSS are not relative but to localhost. I know what to do now.

Sorry about that fellas!

Comment: This has nothing to do with File Sharing permissions.

Comment: i have an opencart website on the other machine in my local network and i am facing the same issue i don,t know how to solve this can you help please @Fisherman

Answer (score 6):

**The pages are not rendered properly because CSS is not being loaded**. In wordpress setting (last tab on left), make sure you change the path to

```
192.168.x.xxx
```

By default, this path is localhost. Although they both mean the same thing, localhost is not interpreted the same as IP address. Like wise computer name is also not interpreted the same as localhost.

I would recommend to change localhost in wordpress setting to your computer name and then access your blog through your computer name, not the IP address, that makes life a little easier.

Also make sure you have shared the folder contain Wordpress + make sure your have enabled exception on firewall for port 80 which is the default port.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking here, there are looooooads of hits for this on google :
http://www.google.co.uk/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=xampp+not+working+over+lan

After a quick browse it appears the firewall on your pc is probably blocking it, as someone noted 'allowed port 80 limiting the scope to my subnet' , try allowing incoming traffic on port 80, restrict it to just your local lan though.

Just as a quick test try turning your firewall off totally and see if it works, if it does you know its a firewall problem and you will then need to open up ports its blocking.

Comment: Yes, I googled all over the place. Most of the questions were about not being able to access the sites period. I can access the address when I type in "http://192.168.x.xxx/mysite/wordpress/" from another computer but the services aren't working.

Comment: have you tried turning off your firewall for a moment just to make sure its not blocking any ports ?